# How to create list of tuples from dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples, sna

I have a dictionary and I want to create a list of tuples between tags. In fact, I want to make a connection between every 2 common tags that come in 2 different titles to draw a graph. How can I do this?

```
data = [
  {
    'title': 'title1', 'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
  },
  {
    'title': 'title2', 'tags': ['tag1','tag2']
  },
  {
    'title': 'title3', 'tags': ['tag2','tag3']
  }
]
```

what I want:

```
edge_list = [(tag1,tag2),(tag2,tag3)]
```

Comment: but your output as nothing to do with the given data, am I right? You are saying that the tagX should be contained in two different titles, right?

Comment: @cards I want pairs of same tags of different titles to be in a tuple

Comment: @cards For example, tag 2 and 3 are both separated in 2 titles, so they are placed in a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to create a function to iterate over the lists and get edges:

```
def get_edges_from_list(l):
    edges = []
    for i,x in enumerate(l[:-1]):
        edges.append((x, l[i+1]))
    return edges
```

then apply, flatten (with sum) and drop_duplicates (with set):

```
set(sum([get_edges_from_list(x['tags']) for x in data], []))
```